# Auto_arima and ARCH

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, arima, garch

I have an `auto_arima` model that works in Python but I want to optimize it using ARCH. I have run an ARCH model on my ARIMA residuals but I do not know what to do with my results.

How do I incorporate Variance, Residual Variance, Mean or Volatility into my ARIMA forecast?
Do I just do e.g. ARIMA Forecast + Variance (or Volatility or Residual Variance or Mean)?

Please explain, also a Python script would help.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

To deal with autocorrelation it is common to use ARMA. To deal with conditional heteroskedasticity it is common to use GARCH. If both patterns are present in your data, you can use ARMA-GARCH.

An **ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(r,s)** model looks like this:
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= c + \varphi_1 x_{t-1} + \dots + \varphi_p x_{t-p} + \theta_1 u_{t-1} + \dots + \theta_q u_{t-q} \quad \text{(cond. mean)}, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \alpha_s u_{t-s}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \beta_r \sigma_{t-r}^2 \quad \text{(cond. variance)}, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.D(0,1),
\end{aligned}
where $D$ is some probability distribution with zero mean and unit variance.

When you fit an ARMA with constant conditional variance, you effectively replace the cond. variance equation by $\sigma_t^2=\sigma_t$.
When you fit a GARCH with constant conditional mean, you effectively replace the cond. mean equation by $\mu_t=\mu$.
If you fit the two separately, you can joint them afterwards to produce ARMA-GARCH as specified above. Thus, you would treat the relevant estimates from your ARMA model as estimates of the $\mu_t$ equation and the relevant estimates from the GARCH model as estimates of the $\sigma_t^2$ equation.

(I do not code in Python, so I am not providing example code.)